# Jmeter store multiple value on single parameter without using Excel file

Tags: java, api, parameters, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Hello everyone is this possible that I will store multiple values on a single parameter. Each call  will alter to Dog, Cat and Rabbit without using excel file. Your response is appreciated. Thank you so much

Example:

TEST-Dog

TEST-Cat

TEST-Rabbit

Expected Result: test parameter will generate account defined values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want each occurrence of the Sampler to use one of the animals as a parameter without using external files you can do it as:

1. Define these animals as JMeter Variables via [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables) configuration element

   [image]
2. Wherever you want to refer the value use [__RandomFromMultipleVars() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomFromMultipleVars) like:

   ```
   ${__RandomFromMultipleVars(value)}
   ```

Demo:

[image]